# Can't dismiss a popup window (other solutions do not work)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to create a simple PopupWindow with a text entry field.

I know there are many questions of this type, but none seem to solve my problem. This is the XML of my popup layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dodaj produkt po identyfikatorze"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:hint="Identyfikator"
        android:minWidth="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/insert_edit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/insert_ok"
            android:text="OK"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/insert_cancel"
            android:text="Anuluj"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I want to create this layout in my main activity when a FAB is pressed. This is how I do it:

```java
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityScrollingBinding binding;
    private int ACTIVITY_LOAD_DATABASE = 1;
    AbstractDatabase database;
    RowAdapter rowAdapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),  AbstractDatabase.class, "magazyn_db")
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        binding = ActivityScrollingBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        FloatingActionButton fab = binding.addCode;
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.println(Log.INFO, "VIEWs", "Showing popup");
                PopupWindow codePopup;

                View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.insert_code, binding.getRoot());

                codePopup = new PopupWindow(popupView);
                codePopup.setFocusable(true);
                codePopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);

                View cancelButton = codePopup.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.insert_cancel);
                cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        codePopup.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                View acceptButton = codePopup.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.insert_ok);
                acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        View editView = codePopup.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.insert_edit);
                        String id = ((EditText)editView).getText().toString().trim();
                        insertNewElement(id);
                        codePopup.dismiss();
                        }
                });
            }
        });
[...]
```

For an unknown reason my popup doesn't go dismissed, both when I click outside of it, or press the cancel button (when I tried to print some logs from the handler, they worked). I have tried many solutions, also inflating it with no root, but then 'showAtPosition' doesn't even show it, and no solutions here on stackoverflow seem to help me even though there are many of them.

Is anyone able to point the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

`public void dismiss ()` Disposes of the popup window. This method can be invoked only after `showAsDropDown(android.view.View)` has been executed. Failing that, calling this method will have no effect.